# SQL: Remove duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I remove duplicates from a table that is set up in the following way?

```
unique_ID | worker_ID | date | type_ID
```

A worker can have multiple type_ID's associated with them and I want to remove any duplicate types. If there is a duplicate, I want to remove the type with the most recent entry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A textbook candidate for the window function row_number():

```
;WITH x AS (
    SELECT unique_ID
          ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_ID,type_ID ORDER BY date) AS rn
    FROM   tbl
    )
DELETE FROM tbl
FROM   x
WHERE  tbl.unique_ID = x.unique_ID
AND    x.rn > 1
```

This also takes care of the situation where a set of dupes on `(worker_ID,type_ID)` shares the same `date`.
See the simplified [demo on data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118656/demo-fro-ryan).

#### Update with simpler version

Turns out, this can be simplified: In SQL Server you can delete from the CTE directly:

```
;WITH x AS (
    SELECT unique_ID
          ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_ID,type_ID ORDER BY date) AS rn
    FROM   tbl
    )
DELETE x
WHERE  rn > 1
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I get the same "The multi-part identifier (unique ID) could not be bound" error.

Comment: @Ryan: `unique_ID` != `unique ID` -  I see a missing underscore.

Comment: I just put 'unique ID' in the comment to represent my table's specific unique ID.

Comment: @Ryan: have you had a look at the link I provided: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118656/demo-fro-ryan
You can test and see that is works there. This is `SQL Server 2008 R2`. Are you running an older installation maybe?

Comment: Yes, and thank you. I came back and tried it again today and it worked. I'm not sure what I was doing yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from table t
 where exists ( select 1 from table t2 
                 where t2.worker_id = t.worker_id
                   and t2.type_id = t.type_id
                   and t2.date < t.date )
```

HTH

Comment: I get the error "The multi-part identifier ... could not be bound". Every change I try and make either results in nothing being returned or more errors. When I turned this into a SELECT statement for testing I didn't get the error, only when attempting to delete.

Comment: @Ryan: this is probably due to a typo. should be `from table t t2` instead of `from table t2`.

Comment: If I do that I get "Incorrect Syntax" errors on 'where' and 't2'.

Comment: This ended up working well, with the exception of not being able to detect duplicates that share the same date.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM @t WHERE unique_Id IN 
(
    SELECT unique_Id FROM 
    (   
        SELECT  unique_Id
                ,Type_Id 
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_Id, type_Id ORDER BY date) AS rn 
        FROM @t 
    ) Q 
    WHERE rn > 1
)
```

And to test...

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    unique_ID  INT IDENTITY,
    worker_ID  INT,
    date  DATETIME,
    type_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 1)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 1)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2, GETDATE(), 1)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE()), 1)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, DATEADD(DAY, 3, GETDATE()), 2)

SELECT * FROM @t

DELETE FROM @t WHERE unique_Id IN 
(
    SELECT unique_Id FROM 
    (   
        SELECT  unique_Id
                ,Type_Id 
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_Id, type_Id ORDER BY date) AS rn 
        FROM @t 
    ) Q 
    WHERE rn > 1
)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use this query

```
delete from worker where unique_id in (
select max(unique_id)  from worker group by  worker_ID , type_ID having count(type_id)>1)
```

here i am assuming worker as your table name

Comment: And the date check requested by the OP?