# Deleting partly duplicate rows in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table, with rowid, userid, productid, and times. once I ordered the table by userid and time. It looks like:

```
u1, t1, p1
u1, t2, p1
u1, t3, p1
u1, t4, p2
u1, t5, p2
u1, t6, p3
u2, t7, p1
u2, t8, p1
u2, t9, p2
u2, t10,p3
 .....
```

I want to delete those rows whose product id is same as the previous row.
therefore the final table should be :

```
u1, t1, p1
u1, t4, p2
u1, t6, p3
u2, t7, p1
u2, t9, p2
u2, t10,p3
.....
```

How can I do this in SQL? Many thanks

Comment: Which version of SQL (Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer, etc)? Also, should you only delete those rows whose product id *and user_id* is the same as the previous row?

Comment: Turns out to be the almost the same solution as here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8216634/939860

Comment: It is SQL server. yes, only delete those with same productid and userid as the previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Simplified version</sup>
Turns out it is for SQL Server, and you can delete from the CTE directly in SQL Server (as hinted by @Royi Namir in the comments below):

```
;WITH x AS (
    SELECT rowid,
           rownumber() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id,productid ORDER BY times) AS rn
    FROM   tbl
    )
DELETE FROM x
WHERE  rn > 1;
```

[Simplified live demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08a81/1).
[Much like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8216634/939860).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Actually: 1.) The original is mine - follow the link. 2.) Your query is wrong again. Exactly like last time.

Comment: 1) - I didnt noticed it was yours. 2) let me check ( the double from)

Comment: its hard to say from his question :  he says : `rowid, userid, productid,` and then he say `u1, t1, p1`. so I used `productIdInsted` - and yes i once again forgot the other partition by. hhhh. I cann assure you it is the last time. :) thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: We live and learn. :) And btw, yes, you need the additional `FROM`. [Try the demo](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118656/demo-fro-ryan).

Comment: Its the kind of things which you know - but since you type fast - you can bypass some....p.s. why the double `from ` can you exaplain?

Comment: The two FROM clauses have a different meaning The first is required for `DELETE FROM`, the second is to add in additional relations. [Read more in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5233/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-erwin-brandstetter)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hi :-) I've just tested and the deletion can be made straight from the CTE   : something like `;WITH CTE AS (
                                            SELECT id
                                                  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [STATUS] ORDER BY id) AS rn
                                            FROM   tbl2
                                        )
DELETE 
FROM   cte WHERE   rn>1
  `

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Cool, that simplifies the syntax. Makes sense for SQL server, too. The same does not work with PostgreSQL. I added the simpler version to my answer. I'll vote for your answer if you fix it up with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH x AS (
    select rowid,  rownumber() 
            over (partition by userid,productid order by rowid) as rn     
    FROM   tbl
    )
DELETE FROM tbl
    WHERE  tbl.rowid= x.rowid
AND    x.rn > 1
```

Comment: You might want to fix your query with your newly acquired SQL-fu skills? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE( prod VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @tmp SELECT DISTINCT PROD FROM tblSource

SELECT TOP 1 FROM tblSource a
JOIN @tmp b ON a.product = b.prod
ORDER BY UserId, TimeId
```

my bad, I didn't read the question completely, since you are wanting to delete, you might want to use Royi's answer.  OTH, you could put my selection into a second temp, then delete in the main table on a left join where the tmp2 is null