# How to select all the duplicates except one?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have database which I must clean up. There are millions of records and I have duplicates (duplicates are those which have the same 2nd column, `C_DataSourceID`). I need to remove all the duplicates except the newest one, according to 3rd column `C_DateCreated`.

I was trying to use this:

```
SELECT C_EmailAddress, C_DataSourceID, C_DateCreated, count(*) 
FROM duplicates GROUP BY C_DataSourceID 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

But it returns duplicates with the amount of the duplicates. Is there a way to get all, but one, duplicates according to `C_DataSourceID`?

I don't have an ID, but I might add ID. The database is empty so far, but it is going to have many records. Should I add ID? I need those records separated not grouped by.

Comment: What database are you using?  And do you have an `id` column or other way to identify each row?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8226999/859154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates that have the same C_DateCreated:

```
select d.C_EmailAddress, d.C_DataSourceID, d.C_DateCreated
from duplicates as d
where d.C_DateCreated != 
    (select max(d2.C_DateCreated) 
     from duplicates d2 
     where d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId and 
         d.C_EmailAddress = d.C_EmailAddress)
```

Not the most performant way of doing things, but it'll work...

Comment: It is working, thank you! Might it cause some speed problems or why it isn't most performant way?

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct as soon as you tell me what if the dateCreated is not unique (because it might happen that user creates 2 different accounts at same day (unfortunately there is no time)). Would you mind telling me? Should I use ID then, or anything other what is unique? Thanks!

Comment: If dateCreated is not unique, all accounts that are created on this exact day are excluded from your query. That means, there will still be duplicates after your cleanup.

Comment: Yes, exactly and unfortunately, anyway your answer is the best, thank you. :)

Comment: Although, if it's a timestamp rather than a simple date it's unlikely that you'll get two created at exactly the same time...

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using ANSI SQL for solving this problem:

```
delete 
    from duplicates d
    where not exists (select 1
                      from duplicates d2
                      where d2.C_DataSourceID = d.C_DataSourceID and
                            d2.C_DateCreated > d.C_DateCreated
                     )
```

However, not all databases support this syntax.

Comment: This could still bring duplicates for equal values of `C_DateCreated` for the same `C_DataSourceID`.

Comment: @Kaf . . . The logic of the query is to identify duplicates according to that column.