# SQL: Remove duplicates (slightly different)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I asked a question similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216437/sql-remove-duplicates) and was given great answers, but it turns out the following way is the way it needs to be done. I've been working on this for several hours now and haven't been able to make too much progress.

How do I remove duplicates from a table that is set up in the following way?

```
unique_ID | worker_ID | date | type_ID
```

A worker can have multiple type_ID's associated with them. I want to remove under the following conditions:

1. Duplicate types for a worker where all types have the same date -
   *Remove all type entries but one*
2. Duplicate types for a worker where one type has a date and the other
   has a null value - *Remove the type entry/entries with the null value*
3. Duplicate types for a worker where both have null date values -
   *Remove all type entries but one*

Number 2 is the only one I'm having an issue with. I think I've got 1 and 3 working.

My code for number 1 per request.

```
Delete from TABLENAME
WHERE unique_ID IN
(
   SELECT MAX(unique_ID)
   FROM TABLENAME
   GROUP BY worker_ID, type_ID, date
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      AND date IS NOT NULL
)
```

I figured number three should be a small alteration of the code used for number 1.

**UPDATE (12/8/2011) - Solution I came up with for condition 2**

```
select
  unique_ID,
  worker_ID,
  type_ID
into #validActive
from
  #tbl
where date is not null

select
  unique_ID,
  worker_ID,
  type_ID
into #nullActive
from #tbl
where date is null

Delete from #tbl where unique_ID in
(
select #nullActive.unique_ID from #validActive join #nullActive on #validActive.worker_ID = #nullActive.worker_ID
where (#validActive.worker_ID = #nullActive.worker_ID and #validActive.type_ID = #nullActive.type_ID)
)
```

[Demo of solution](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120887)

Comment: Can you post the query you have with #1 and 3 working to give us a place to start?

Comment: I've added my code for number 1. I figure number 3 will be similar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up coming up with:

```
select
  unique_ID,
  worker_ID,
  type_ID
into #validActive
from
  #tbl
where date is not null

select
  unique_ID,
  worker_ID,
  type_ID
into #nullActive
from #tbl
where date is null

Delete from #tbl where unique_ID in
(
select #nullActive.unique_ID from #validActive join #nullActive on #validActive.worker_ID = #nullActive.worker_ID
where (#validActive.worker_ID = #nullActive.worker_ID and #validActive.type_ID = #nullActive.type_ID)
)
```

[Demo of solution](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120887)

Comment: A solution requiring a loop is not a best practice. The approach recommended by Ben Thul will be significantly more performant, safer transactionally, and simpler to read.

Comment: I came up with a non-loop oriented solution and have edited my post to show the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
   select unique_ID, worker_ID, [date], type_ID,
   row_number() over (partition by worker_id order by isnull([date], '1753-01-01') desc) as [rn]
   from your_table
)
delete cte where [rn] <> 1
```

You should be able to adapt this solution to your other cases as well.

Comment: This seems to return every single type, regardless of duplication. If you partition by the type_ID as well then it returns all duplicate types for a worker. But even then it returns duplicate types that have different, non-null, dates.

Comment: I'm not sure what you could even mean... how would a delete statemnet "return" something? I suspect you're mis-reading something.

Comment: I meant that when I ran the select statement inside of the delete statement, to check and see what it would be deleting, it seemed to return every single type, regardless of duplication.

Comment: If you're trying to get a sense of what will be deleted, just replace the word "delete" with "select * from".

Answer (score 0):

This may be rather more complex than it has to be,  but it will do the trick if what you are looking for is ending up with one row per worker/type/date triplet except in the case where a date is null and a date is not, which I think is what you wanted?

```
with maxDate AS (
SELECT worker_ID, type_id, MAX(date) as maxDate 
FROM Table
GROUP BY worker_ID, type_ID
)
DELETE x
FROM Table x
JOIN (
SELECT unique_ID
, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY w.worker_ID, w.type_ID, COALESCE(date, maxDate) ORDER BY date DESC) AS rowNumber
FROM Table w
JOIN maxDate m
ON w.worker_id = m.worker_id
AND w.type_id = m.type_id
) y
ON x.unique_id = y.unique_id
WHERE y.rowNumber <> 1
```

Comment: This seems to have the same issue as Ben's, in that it seems to return every single type, regardless of duplication.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question then - one row per worker or one row per worker/type

Comment: One row per worker/type combination. I apologize if I made that ambiguous.