# Remove duplicate entries without primary key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have this table MSSQL :

```
EntityNo int
City nvarchar(MAX)
Province nvarchar(MAX)
EntityDate datetime
```

EntityNo should be unique, but it's not primary key. How can I remove one of the duplicate entries from this table? Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](http://donotforgetitmaster.blogspot.in/2016/05/another-simple-way-to-find-remove.html).

Comment: Please mention DBMS.

Comment: @TanjimRahman it's MSSQL, if that's you are asking

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216437/sql-remove-duplicates

Comment: I will go with @Husen's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this query

```
DELETE a FROM (
    SELECT row_number() over(partition by EntityNo order by EntityNo) as RowNo
    FROM Entity
) AS a WHERE RowNo > 1
```

Comment: This will delete only one row, right? Not both of duplicate entries?

Comment: yes, it will left only one entry and else will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `rowid` in oracle like this:

```
DELETE FROM 
   table_name A
WHERE 
  a.rowid > 
   ANY (
     SELECT 
        B.rowid
     FROM 
        table_name B
     WHERE 
        A.col1 = B.col1
     AND 
        A.col2 = B.col2
        );
```

Equivalent of row id in `sql server` is `%%physloc%%` which is not supported. But you can also add your own temp rowid to this table and give sequencial value to this column and use it.